# PID control, integral and derivative of zero?

Tags: integration, derivatives, control-theory

I am studying about PID control in engineering and i am thinking about the case when error e(t) is zero as discussed in below SE EE question
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/462968/confusion-in-pid-loop/462973#462973

Obiviously 1st term "P" will get to zero when it is multiplied by 0 but
What will be the output of integral and derivative blocks if we have error e(t)=0 ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on past history, particularly the integral block. You might well have some "momentum" carrying you past the setpoint due to the integral term. In addition, you might not approach the setpoint at a smaller and smaller velocity. If you cross the setpoint with a distinct download slope, then the derivative term will not be zero.

In conclusion, the best way to think about $P,I,$ and $D$ is that they are independent variables.

Comment: The effect of integral term and derivative term will not get to zero when multiplied by zero value of e(t)??because any thing multiplied by zero is also 0

Comment: No: the $I$ and $D$ terms are not $e(t),$ but $\dot{e}(t)$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^t e(\tau)\,d\tau,$ respectively. And just as $f(x)=x$ can be zero at $x=0,$ but have a derivative of $1$, so the derivative is *independent of the function value.*